# Tag Release Version TFS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, tfs

I am trying to tag a release version on TFS like a feature that GIT have.

For example my release version 1.2.0 and I just want to tag something like;

```
git tag <tagname>
```

Are there any feature in TFS ? If there isn't how can I solve this ?

Thank you

Comment: See if this [helps](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/use-labels-take-snapshot-your-files).

Comment: I missed that, thats also good article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the [tf label](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/label-command-team-foundation-version-control) command.

E.g.

```
tf label src rel_1.2.0
```

adds a label to the workspace folder `src`.

Comment: Really thank you for your clear answer. That totally solves my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a command line task in your release definition and just use git command `git tag -a vx.x $(Build.SourceVersion) -m "xxx"`
to add a tag, check the screenshot below:

[image]